# "Command not found" error in bash script after loop

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write a bash script on Debian 10 that:

- looks into a certain directory
- discovers all its subdirectories
- checks which one has a file `fullchain.pem`
- converts this file with `openssl` and copies the result to another directory.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
ROOTPATH="/etc/letsencrypt/live"

for PATH in $ROOTPATH/*
do
  if test -f "${PATH}/fullchain.pem"; then
    openssl pkcs12 -export -out $PATH/fullchain.pfx -in $PATH/fullchain.pem -inkey $PATH/privkey.pem -passin pass:whatever -passout pass:whatever
    cp $PATH/fullchain.pem ./Server/fullchain.pfx
  fi
done
```

**The problem:** Both `openssl` and `cp` cause a `command not found` error. It appears that only `echo` works inside or after the loop. Everything else, even basic commands (ie. `touch`) all throw this error.

Naturally I have `openssl` installed, and there's no way the `cp` command can be missing. They both run from the command line.

I found that it only happens inside or after the loop. If I try to invoke `openssl` or `cp` before the `for PATH...` line, they run correctly.

Even this simplified version throws the same error:

```
for PATH in "/etc/letsencrypt/live/*"
do
  cp
done
```

What's wrong with the loop, why is it causing such a weird error?

Comment: Don't use `PATH` as your own shell variable - that clobbers the executable search path `PATH`. In fact, best avoid ALLCAPS variable names altogether.

Comment: Now I feel a bit stupid. Thanks, that really was the reason!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `PATH` to something else. It is best to avoid using any environment variables as an iterator.